# How to send an object in RedirectView

Tags: mongodb, spring-mvc, model-view-controller, spring-data

```
@Controller
public class PersonController {  
@Autowired  
private PersonService personService;

@RequestMapping(value = "/person", method = RequestMethod.GET)  
public String getPersonList(@ModelAttribute ModelMap model,Person person) {  
    model.addAttribute("personList", personService.listSpecificPerson(person));
    return "output";  //this will redirect to output.jsp
}  

@RequestMapping(value = "/person/save", method = RequestMethod.POST)  
public View createPerson(@ModelAttribute Person person, ModelMap model) {
    if(StringUtils.hasText(person.getId())) {  
        personService.updatePerson(person);  
    } else {  
        person=personService.addPerson(person);  
    }  
    return new RedirectView("/RegistrationSpringWithMongo/person");  
 }  
}
```

Method in Service Class:
    public Person listSpecificPerson(Person person) {
         return mongoTemplate.findById(person.getId(), Person.class, COLLECTION_NAME);
    }

In the above code in return statement of the "createPerson" method I want to pass the object "person" and receive that object in the "getPersonList" method and want to use.
Anyone Please help me in this regard.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

since you want to redirect client to different URL, you can use [flash attributes](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/spring-mvc-flash-attribute-example/) to store the "person" object inbetween the HTTP requests.